# Lua: Finding a token in a delimited string

Tags: string, lua

I have a string with a set of delimited tokens that looks something like this:

```
local str = "foo;bar;baz"
```

I'd like to be able to **accurately** tell if a given token is in this string or not:

```
in_str("foo", str) -- true
in_str("bar", str) -- true
in_str("baz", str) -- true
in_str("ba", str) -- false
in_str("foo;", str) -- false
```

Using PHP and regular expressions, I would accomplish the desired effect with something like this:

```
function in_str($needle, $haystack) {
    return (bool)preg_match('/(^|;)' . preg_quote($needle, '/') . '(;|$)/', $haystack);
}
```

I'm unsure how to translate this logic into Lua, though.  I'd also rather be able to do it in vanilla Lua, without any plugins/extensions/etc.  I'd also like it to be reasonably efficient.  The only way I've managed to implement this correctly thus far involves splitting the string into a table, and then iterating it, which is obviously very inefficient.

Comment: `which is obviously very inefficient.`  -- Why is it obviously inefficient? Regexes are typically slower.

Comment: Because the linear search is `O(n)`, and that's not even counting having to split the string every time.

Comment: Unless your string has thousands of tokens in it (or you're processing thousands of such strings), this is probably premature optimization.  If you're building a compiler, there might be better ways of doing this, like putting the tokens in a dictionary.  Then you'd be at O(1), not O(n).

Comment: This function would be called dozens of times per second, so I don't feel that it's premature optimization.

Comment: It's a real-time system?

Comment: Yes, it's a real-time system.  Sorry for not mentioning that earlier.

Comment: OK.  Well, it will be interesting to find out if the Regex version really turns out to be faster.

Comment: I don't necessarily want a regex implementation.  I only offered it up as an example of a working implementation of what I need to accomplish.  As far as I know, I can't do it the regex way in Lua without an extension anyway, but I'm rather new to the language.

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't just search the string for `foo` using `string.find`?

Comment: Yes; because it would erroneously match tokens where `foo` was a substring of a token, rather than the token itself (e.g. `abcfooxyz`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a sample of the code at work: [LINK](http://codepad.org/AHLCl5MN)

```
local str = "foo;bar;baz;and;some;more;random;data;in;here"
function check(sString, sData)
  print( string.find(";"..sString..";", ";"..sData..";") )
end
check( str, "foo" )
check( str, "bar" )
check( str, "ba" )
check( str, "baz" )
check( str, "random" )
check( str, "stuff" )
```

Comment: I've edited this answer to fix some scenarios where it gave false positives/negatives.  It appears to be the most efficient method, though.  Thanks.

Comment: @drrcknlsn I tried that myself too, though my method was a bit different, [here](http://codepad.org/vg72tQCE)

Comment: Yeah, that method is definitely more fault-tolerant.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no `|` (logical OR) operator in Lua's pattern-match API, you could do something like this instead:

```
function in_str(needle, haystack)
  return (haystack:find(';' .. needle .. ';') or
          haystack:find('^' .. needle .. ';') or
          haystack:find(';' .. needle .. '$')) ~= nil
end

local str = "foo;bar;baz"

print(in_str("foo", str))  -- true
print(in_str("bar", str))  -- true
print(in_str("baz", str))  -- true
print(in_str("ba", str))   -- false
print(in_str("foo;", str)) -- false
```